# How can I select only the 4 digit numbers surrounded by paren's using xpath?

Tags: xslt, xpath

If I have:

```
<list>
<item>ABCD<item>
<item>(EFGH)<item>
<item>(4567)<item>
<item>(123)<item>
<item>(56789)<item>
<item>6789<item>
<item>ABC<item>
</list>
```

and ONLY want to get back 4-digit numeric values surrounded by parens - the (4567), what xpath expression can I use in my xslt?

```
<xsl:for-each select="//list/item[EXPRESSION_HERE]" >
<result><xsl:value-of select="." /></result>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Should (0000) or (0001) or (0010) be returned, or not? And do you want the result as `(4567)` or just as `4567`? In case there is: `<item>   (4567)    </item>`, should in this case `(4567)` or  "   (4567)  "  be returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
/list/item[translate(., '123456789', '000000000') = '(0000)']
```